# How to see the total space used and available in aws aurora schema

Tags: amazon-aurora

Do any one know how to see the total space used and available in aws aurora schema, also the memory of the cluster within DB itself using queries. We are using AWS aurora psql and we don't have console, hence we want to try the same from queries like we will do for oracle.

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not doable using a SQL query in aurora, specifically the volume size. As an alternative, if you do have AWS CLI access, you should be able to query Cloudwatch metrics under "AWS/RDS" namespace to get these metrics in a more reliable and accurate manner. The ones you are interested in are "VolumeBytesUsed" and "CPUUtilization" if I'm not mistaken.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html